# What is the Product of the Orders of all Elements in a Symmetric Group?

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

I need to determine the product of all element orders in a symmetric group size $N$. For example, if my group is size $N = 3$, then the answer would be 
$$1(123) * 2(132) * 2(321) * 2(213) * 3(312) * 3(231) = 72$$ 
The end result should be calculated mod $1000000009$. Obviously this number gets very big, and I was wondering if the mod could somehow help reduce the calculations. Memoization and caching results are also a possible method I have thought of. Thank you.

Comment: I don't see the need for the modular arithmetic you have used.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: @Shaun the idea is that as you go, the numbers (product) gets large very quickly, so in order to keep things in a reasonable range, the mod is used. Think of it as simply making the number fit inside an int. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: Please do not deface your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A much faster way than multiplying the orders of all the elements as you check each one is to loop over all cycle types. The cycle type of an element of $S_n$ is a [partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) of $n$, that is a nonincreasing list of positive integers whose sum is $n$. This represents the length of the cycles in a decomposition of the element into disjoint cycles. The order of an element of cycle type $\lambda=(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_k)$ is the least common multiple of $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_k$. This gives you the order $o_\lambda$. Then you just need to know the number of elements of cycle type $\lambda$, which the non-accepted answer tells you here:

[Calculating quantity of elements of a specific cycle-type in alternating and symmetric groups.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1192995/calculating-quantity-of-elements-of-a-specific-cycle-type-in-alternating-and-sym)

That answer treats the cycle type in opposite order, i.e. it treats it as a nondecreasing sequence of integers. Given that number of elements $m$, you multiply by $o_\lambda^m$ to account for cycle type $\lambda$. To speed things up, you can do [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).